# Safe to free allocated data after vkUnmapMemory?

Tags: c, vulkan

I'm attempting to fill a vertex buffer but the catch is that the vertex data is allocated on the heap.

```
unsigned char *vertices = (unsigned char*)calloc(n, sizeof(unsigned char));

...

void* data;
vkMapMemory(device, vertexBufferMemory, 0, bufferInfo.size, 0, &data);
    memcpy(data, vertices, (size_t) bufferInfo.size);
vkUnmapMemory(device, vertexBufferMemory);
```

Is it safe to free the vertices pointer after vkUnmapMemory?

Comment: Off topic: you should never unmap memory unless you're going to delete the device memory in Vulkan. If you're allocating mappable memory, map it *once*, and leave it mapped forever. There is no harm in doing so, and if you do, the question becomes meaningless.

Comment: It’s safe to free vertices after the last time you use it. That would be the `memcpy`. Vulkan has no knowledge of that memory.